# libstdc++.6.dylib and architecture armv7 error, when I trying to build AS3 mobile iPhone project with ane

Tags: ios, iphone, actionscript-3, armv7

I have `AS3` mobile project that uses ane for iPhone.

When I try to export release build for iPhone I get an error: Error occurred while packaging the application:

```
ld: file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x6c 0x69 0x62 0x73 0x74 0x64 0x63 0x2b 0x2b 0x2e 0x36 0x2e 0x30 0x2e 0x39 0x2e ) which is not the architecture being linked (armv7): C:\\Users\\Emily\\Documents\\iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib for architecture armv7

Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

I'm using `flash builder 4.7` on windows 8, `air 13.0` and `iPhoneOS7.0.sdk`

So, what do you think it can be? How can i correctly compile my project to ipa?

Comment: That's confusing; why is there a Windows path in the error message?

Comment: Oh well, I'll stay out of it as I've no experience in this area.